# Зелёное подчеркивание String may not be zero terminated

Tags: c++, strlen

После ввода следующего кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
char s1[80], s2[80];

std::cout << "Enter two lines: ";

gets_s(s1); gets_s(s2);

std::cout << "Their lenghts equal: "<< strlen(s1);
std::cout << ' ' << strlen(s2) << '\n';

if (!strcmp(s1, s2))
    std::cout << "Lines are equal \n";
else std::cout << "Lines are not equal \n";

strcat_s(s1, s2);
std::cout << s1 << '\n';

strcpy_s(s1, s2);
std::cout << s1 << " & " << s2 << ' ';
std::cout << "Now equal\n";
return 0;
}
```

В Visual Studio получаю :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускается , вроде нормально, но смущает подчёркивание

Как исправить?

Comment: Это русскоязычный сегмент. По-русски, пожалуйста. Или в англоязычный сегмент с вопросом на английском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/code-quality/c6054?view=msvc-170 .

> Это предупреждение означает, что для функции, требующей строку,
> завершающуюся нулем, была передана строка, не завершающаяся нулем.
> Функция, которая ожидает строку, завершающуюся нулем, может искать
> ноль за концом буфера. Эта ошибка может привести к ошибке переполнения
> буфера или сбою злоумышленника. Программа должна убедиться, что
> передаваемая строка заканчивается нулем.

Чтобы исправить это предупреждение, перед вызовом функции следует завершать s1 и s2 нулем что-то типо: `s1[79] = '\0';`

Comment: char s1[80] = { s1[79] = '\0'}, s2[80] = { s2[79] = '\0'}; Сработало. Спасибо! 
Или так тоже работает ...
char s1[80], s2[80];
 s1[79] = '\0';
 s2[79] = '\0';...

Comment: мне кажется второй вариант тоже должен работать, попробуй, но если нет то можно и первый использовать, в принципе он даже удобнее

Comment: Работают оба) Спасибо!